# Using $(this) with multiple selectors, can you refer to one and not the other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Let's say you have two selectors like this:

```
$(".class1, .class2").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

It seems that `$(this)` refers to both selectors. Is there a way to only refer to one and not the other? (I dont mean just using `.class1` or `.class2` because I want it to refer to the element that is being clicked if there are multiple elements with those classes.)

I just realized that you could write out the same thing twice, but that's not very nice:

```
$(".class1").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(.element).show();
});

    $(".class2").click(function() {
       $(.element).show();
});
```

Comment: This is actually a very good question. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ($(this).is(".class2"))
```

Comment: While this solves the issue addressed in the question, it should be noted that the question itself is not accurate--as mu is too short [mentions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804806/using-this-with-multiple-selectors-can-you-refer-to-one-and-not-the-other/6804834#6804834), `this` refers only to the element that was clicked.

Comment: You can also use $(this).hasClass("class2")

Answer (score 5):

No, in here:

```
$(".class1, .class2").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

`this` in the callback function refers only to the single element that was clicked.

Click on the button and see for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/GyEck/